# unable to find softLayer api to cancel the primary vlans

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I want to cancel the public/private vlans which comes with server ordering.

Please share softlayer api for cancellation of primary vlans ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Vlan purchased

If you purchased the vlan, it's necessary to cancel servers inside of this and then you can proceed to cancel the vlan through its billingItem, the requests that will help with that:

**To get information from vlans and their billing items**

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkVlans?objectMask=mask[billingItem.id]

Method: Get
```

**To cancel vlan billind item**

Once you get the vlan's billing item identifier, you can use this request:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Billing_Item_Cancellation_Request/createObject

Method: Post

{  
   "parameters":[  
      {  
         "accountId":123123,
         "items":[  
            {  
               "billingItemId":101726027,
               "immediateCancellationFlag":true
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Replace: **123123** with your accountId and **101726027** with the vlan's billing item identifier

---

### Vlan provided by SoftLayer

If the vlans for your server was provided by SoftLayer, they will be removed when the server is already cancelled, so you just need to cancel the server.